Correct RealTek network driver isn't connecting to internet
I've been having issues with my wifi connectivity. Occasionally my computer just stopped recognizing wifi's altogether - I look for networks in the dropdown and nothing's there.
I figured it was a network drivers issue, so I did some searching for a solution. I discovered that although everyone seems to hate RealTek network cards, there's a solution on AskUbuntu that gives a driver for 18.04. Apparently that project is no longer maintained, and I'm on 22.04; I found this article listing another PPA. I found the appropriate driver for me based on my lspci:
$ lspci | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

which would be rtl8822ce-dkms. I installed this, following the steps outlined in the article; now my wifi doesn't work at all. It shows it's connected to my network, but nothing comes through when I ping. And my old network driver, which gave me spotty internet, was called something like rtl8821ce-dkms, which is just altogether the wrong network card.
Does anyone have any tips to solve this? Am I installing the wrong driver, or doing something else incorrect?

Can you please add some details what you mean with "having issues with my wifi connectivity"? Does it work at least sometimes, or not at all? Always meaning under Ubuntu. You "figured it was a network drivers issue", how or why did you come to that conclusion? Do you see any related entries in your syslog or dmesg output?

After disabling secure boot from the BIOS, please connect via either ethernet cable, USB or Bluetooth tethering from your phone, whatever, and try the following sets of commands
lspci > tmp_out
lshw -C network > tmp_out2
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt remove broadcom-sta-dkms bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-source broadcom-sta-dkms broadcom-sta-common && reboot

and let me know how it went.
Please also do your due diligence in looking up what you are doing. All these commands are innocuous, however innocuous commands in an unhealthy environment can cause trouble.
If this doesn't work, backup all your files (something you should have already done) and re-install a supported ubuntu distro, this has worked for me so far as a last poor man's solution with wifi problems.
